# Handle Activity with Fragments with different layout for portrait and landscape

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` with `Fragment` in it, and it has different layout xml files for landscape and portrait mode.

I try to use `onConfigurationChanged()` like this:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.hdmain);
}
```

Where `hdmain.xml` is put in `layout-land` and `layout-port` folder. Then I meet the Fragment lifecycle problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #9: Duplicate id 0x7f0c0019, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for org.sais.hdmeridian.HDMainActivity$TabFragment
```

It looks like the Fragment is still there, and since I changed the layout of Activity, a new Fragment is created then duplicated.

What's a smart way to avoid this? Or does Android has some better solution to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the tag `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Activity in the Manifest.
This prevents the onCreate to be executed on every turn of the devices, and solves most duplicate errors for me.

Comment: If I don't then `onConfigurationChanged()` will be no meaning. Of course I did.